# Move cursor to write in specific line of a text file with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to know how I can use VBA to replace a specific line of a text file by another text, and to write in specific zone of the text file by moving the cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to keep track of the positions yourself and apply the logic accordingly.

Something like this:

```
Dim text As String, allText As String
Dim lineNumber As Integer

' Open read handle.
Open "C:\sometext.txt" For Input As #1

allText = ""
lineNumber = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    lineNumber = lineNumber + 1
    Line Input #1, text

    ' Assume you want to replace line 5.
    If lineNumber = 5 Then
        text = "My new value"
    End if

    allText = allText & vbCrLf & text
Loop

' Close read handle.
Close #1


' Output the new text to a separate file.
Open "C:\updatedtext.txt" For Append As #1
Write #1, allText
Close #1
```

Comment: There is still a small problem : when I use this technique, I get two double quotes at the first line of the updatedtext file, how can I remove them ? @Jason Faulkner

Comment: There is still a small problem : when I use this technique, the text is between two double quotes in the updatedtext file, how can I remove them ? @Jason Faulkner

Comment: @otus - Try `Print #1` instead of `Write #1`.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Dim TextString As Variant
  'read text from file
TextString = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\sometext.txt").ReadAll, Chr(13) & Chr(10))

  'change your text here as TextString(#Line - 1) = "Text"
  'still assume you want to replace line 5
TextString(4) = "New Text"

  'write back in file
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("C:\sometext.txt").Write (Join(TextString, Chr(13) & Chr(10)))
```

I think it's pretty simple cuz there is only one line to read and another one to write. No loops or closing files or anything like that.